# Breaking all frames when clicking URL within last frame

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage with some frames within each other in it. Last frame loads a website with many URLs. Some URLs have `target="_top"` and some have `target="_blank"`. When I click to URL with `target="_top"` it breaks all frames on my parent page and load this URL, but when I click URL with `target="_blank"` it leaves my parent page as is (with frames) and opens this URL in a new window. Now the question: how to do that when URL with `target="_blank"` clicked, beside the opening URL in a new window it breaks all frames in my parent page and close it? Thanks

Comment: remove target="_blank" .. it will open in the same window.

Comment: I suppose you wouldn't accept "Stop using frames! This isn't 1995!" as an answer. Pity. Too bad reading the manual isn't an option, as it would have answered this question for you before you wasted our time with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="your/url" target="_blank" onclick="window.location.href = this.href;">
```

Does that work? I'm not sure I'm entirely understanding the situation. Or do you want to "close" the parent page, e.g.

```
<a href="your/url" target="_blank" onclick="window.close();">
```